# How to create a virtual machine server image from a physical windows 2008 server?

Tags: virtualization

Is there a tool that can take a windows server 2008 and make a vdh or vmdk out of that box?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yup.  Take a look at [VMware Converter](http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/).

Comment: Thanks Shane for being prompt. Looks like it's a FREE tool. Am I right?

Comment: @AndyConan Indeed you are, though I believe you need to register on their site for the download.

Comment: This doesn't suffer from chipset differences and not being able to boot?

Comment: @tim - I've only done windows machines, but no, no issues with chipsets or HAL etc.

Answer (score 3):

Also, the SysInternals guys have [Disk2vhd](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415), which converts to a vhd, as the name implies...

I've used it successfully in a production environment several times.